# How do you input initialize and add days to dates? (java)

Tags: java, days

I am trying to build a program that libraries can use. The user inputs the date they loaned the book, and it calculates that date + 5 days (when the book is due). Then checks if the current date is before or after the due date. Then says if it is late or not.

Comment: So what do you want exactly?

Comment: What do you expecting from people, do you want them to write your code from scratch. Kindly share what you have tried till now and what issue you are facing

Answer (score 1):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` to take the user input (as a `String`), and
convert it to a `Date`. Use `Calendar` for adding days to a given `Date`.

See also:

[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

[Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

[Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead and then you can call `plusDays()` on a `DateTime` object. There is also an `isBefore()` method as well. Here is a simple example:

```
DateTime loanDate = new DateTime();
DateTime dueDate = new DateTime().plusDays(8);
DateTime date = loanDate.plusDays(5);
System.out.println(date.isBefore(dueDate));
```

This returns `true` as the date is before the due date.